# UIControlEventProxy or UIControlEventProxy.Activate()

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

Is anyone familiar with UIControlEventProxy or UIControlEventProxy.Activate() or have any documentation on what this UIControlEvent means? I am getting a crash in my application and the stacktrace states:

```
Xamarin Exception Stack:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () <0x103c7ee44 + 0x000a4> in <8fb993547ddc482abf45058220aeb79d#0c0d9011f50c6878aed1b494d399c789>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) <0x103c75db8 + 0x00043> in <8fb993547ddc482abf45058220aeb79d#0c0d9011f50c6878aed1b494d399c789>:0
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) <0x103c75d10 + 0x00053> in <8fb993547ddc482abf45058220aeb79d#0c0d9011f50c6878aed1b494d399c789>:0
  at iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) <0x102b9c61c + 0x00033> in <e9551bcb70aa4f99a5c6812167107484#0c0d9011f50c6878aed1b494d399c789>:0
```

This crash happens when a user taps a hyperlink that navigates to a URL specified in my code.

I can provide code per-request, but the flow goes something like this in Psuedo:

1.User Taps

2.Calls LoadURLAsync()

a. Checks if URL is valid using FormUtils.isURLValid(string url)
b. if true, go to specified URL
c. if not, display a dialog popup

All actions within this method are wrapped in try/catch.

Again, I think I can solve the issue, but I'm not finding ANYTHING on UIControlEventProxy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: UIControlEventProxy is just a [Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents). You get a null reference and you should check which instance is null at that point you run the code.

Comment: So, the issue is this crash is happening in production and I get reports that include events, stacktrace, etc about the crash. I am trying to reproduce this crash locally just by looking at the stack trace, but cant. Nothing crashes. So, was just curious if anyone had any info on UIControlEventProxy.

Comment: You can read the source code [UIControlEventProxy](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/main/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs#L20).